# SQL to function in Codeigniter returns row

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I'm trying to get an entire row values from a new SQL query so.

How can I make a function

```
Select * from table1 t1,table2 t2,table3 t3 where t1.t1_id=t2.t1_id and t3.id=t2.t3_id
```

to something like this :
In model page

```
public function getID_researcher($lastname){
$query = $this->db->get_where('researcher', array('lastname' => $lastname));
return $query->row_array();
}
```

I need to return one row result base on the lastname which is from table1

To clarify here, 'researcher' is the table where it gets data but what I want is the new SQL for me to get the data.

I tried this one but still error.

```
public function getID_researcher($lastname){
$sql = = $this->db->query('Select * from table1 t1,table2 t2,table3 t3 where t1.t1_id=t2.t1_id and t3.id=t2.t3_id');

$query = $this->db->get_where($sql, array('lastname' => $lastname));
return $query->row_array();
}
```

Comment: What is the `get_where` returning, is it an array?

Comment: @miltonb it is an array. But as you can see, 'researcher' is where the table it get. But what I want to get data from is from my new sql.

Answer (score 0):

to use this query

```
Select * from table1 t1,table2 t2,table3 t3 where t1.t1_id=t2.t1_id and t3.id=t2.t3_id
```

you can try to use active record db 'join' like this:

```
$this->db->from('table1 t1');
$this->db->join('table2 t2', 't1.t1_id = t2.t1_id', 'left');
$this->db->join('table3 t3', 't3.id = t2.t3_id', 'left');
$this->db->where('lastname', $lastname);
$query = $this->db->get();
$c = 0;
foreach($query->result() as $q){
  $result[$c]['name'] = $q->lastname;
  // put move variable here
$c++;
}
return $result;
```

hope this help

Comment: When I view my View Page It says Undefined index:age, etc.